# BigQuery function in CASE optimisation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

A question about BigQuery engine and CASE optimization.

On the following query:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN UPPER(name) = 'JOHN' THEN 1
        WHEN UPPER(name) = 'MIKE' THEN 2
        WHEN UPPER(name) = 'RON' THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END AS score
FROM
  table
```

Is using the function UPPER on each WHEN is going to cost computing power for each WITH? Or the BigQuery engine knows how to optimise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid concern - just use

```
SELECT
  CASE UPPER(name)
    WHEN 'JOHN' THEN 1
    WHEN 'MIKE' THEN 2
    WHEN 'RON' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END AS score
FROM
  table
```

meantime, I would expected BigQuery engine does know how to optimize version in your question it :o)

Comment: Thanks! I guess they do optimise it. I tested a few queries while the values hardcoded and computed and its almost the same run time so I guess its optimized

Answer (score 1):

`upper` itself will use a trivial amount of CPU. It's a very simple function. How you're using it requires no disk access (see below). Whether or not BigQuery optimizes it to a single `upper` call or not, it should have little effect on the query performance.

---

Where `upper` can get you into trouble is if it is used in a `where` clause.

```
select *
from foo
where upper(name) = 'JOHN'
```

In a traditional SQL database, this query would be unable to use an index on `name` slowing down the query considerably as it would have to scan the whole table.

However, BigQuery is not a traditional SQL database and that should also perform well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I gave the UPPER function as an example

Comment: @dasdasd The performance concern with queries is typically about how many rows it has to search... though BigQuery is a bit different than traditional SQL databases. Running functions on the data in the found rows is generally not a concern. Since most are [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), the same input gives the same output with no side effects, BigQuery might even have them [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (cached) so they cost no more than a hash table lookup.